# Debian Squeeze: Trackpad on EEE PC 1000HA acts like slate

Tags: touchpad, debian-squeeze

I'm using Debian on an Asus Eee PC 1000HA.  It works flawlessly, except that the built-in trackpad acts as if it was a slate.  That is, if I touch the upper-left quadrant of the trackpad, the mouse pointer "teleports" to the upper left of the netbook's screen.  If I touch the bottom center, the pointer teleports to the bottom center of the screen.

I currently have no xorg.conf.  I have tried various settings for the mouse in xorg.confs that I created, and none of them did more than disable the trackpad entirely.  The trackpad works perfectly in Windows XP (shipped with the Eee) and in Ubuntu.  Debian works fine with the (USB) mouse.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Debian [wiki site](http://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad) gives a lot of info. It showed me how to turn off the touchpad altogether, it gets in my way and I prefer using a mouse anyway :-)  However, it seems it can also set up multitouch functions.

It works fine with Squeeze on my Eee 1001HA.

Comment: It isn't a Synaptics pad, but thanks. As mentioned in my comment on alpha1's answer, the synaptics software has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Install snyaptiks and configure it.

I have a 1000HE with opensuse 11.3 and it works out of the box, minus the tapping, which was configured in the KDE mouse settings.

Comment: I can't locate a package named "synaptiks" and "synaptics" packages are already installed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think thats what i meant...my speling is not good ;)